# Jsp exception when Upgrading from Struts 2.0 to Struts 2.5

Tags: java, jsp, configuration, struts2, freemarker

Some pages of my application run just fine. But then we get to this code:

```xml
<s:form id="filter" action="./filtro_BuscaAdm.html" validate="false">
    <s:hidden  key="newFiltro" value="true"/>
    <s:textfield id="buscaGen" key="campoBusca" />
    <input type="text" name="x" class="displayNone"/>
    <s:submit onclick="return validarBusca();" label="Filtrar" targets="dados" 
                value="Filtrar" type="image" src="../images/searchButton.png" "/>
</s:form>
```

The following exceptions occurs when rendering this page:

> ERROR ClosingUIBean Could not open template 
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.struts2.components.ServletUrlRenderer.renderFormUrl(ServletUrlRenderer.java:135)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.components.Form.populateComponentHtmlId(Form.java:232)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.evaluateParams(UIBean.java:816)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.components.ClosingUIBean.start(ClosingUIBean.java:55)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doStartTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:54)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.decorators.default_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fform_005f0(default_jsp.java:1483)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.decorators.default_jsp._jspService(default_jsp.java:326)

and

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.evaluateParams(UIBean.java:824)
>     at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.end(UIBean.java:535)    at
>   org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:42)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.decorators.default_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fhidden_005f0(default_jsp.java:1542)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.decorators.default_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fform_005f0(default_jsp.java:1493)

If I change the `<s:form>` to `<form>`, it renders normally

in other pages, `<s:form>` tags are rendered normally

I've been at it for weeks. We use maven to resolve the dependencies

This is the step by step I've been writing with my discoverys:

1. **Change the jar version in pom (duh)**
2. **ActionContextCleanUp filter is deprecated. remove it**
3. **FilterDispatcher is now StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter**
4. **update commons-lang, commons-fileupload, remove xwork and ognl jars**
5. **Change struts.xml accordingly (interceptors name and header version declaration)**

after those steps, I am able to deploy the application without build erros. Then I ran in several jsp erros and have been resolving them one by one. So far I've discovered that:

**an `<s:>` tag inside a `<form>` will trigger an "freemarker" exception. "S" tags are only allowed inside "S" components**

Other info:

The Javax.servlet version is 2.4

I can add xwork jar to the classpath. It makes no difference. But I think I should not add it because the core of it is included within struts-2.5-core.jar

I've been over apache.org migration guides and stackoverflow, but couldn't find anything related to this

Here is the web.xml file, full. The "BrainwebFilterDispatcher" Filter extends StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">

    <display-name>Petz</display-name>

    <!-- Define the basename for a resource bundle for I18N -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>messages</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>br.com.stoom.web.SessionCounter</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>threadFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>br.com.stoom.threads.ThreadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>securityFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>br.com.stoom.web.SecurityFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>exportFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>aberturaEmailFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>br.com.stoom.web.AberturaEmailFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>br.com.stoom.web.RewriteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>messageFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>br.com.stoom.web.MessageFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>lazyLoadingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>lojaFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>br.com.stoom.web.LojaFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>



    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts</filter-name>
        <filter-class>br.com.stoom.web.BrainwebFilterDispatcher</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
            <param-value>br.com.stoom.web</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>cacher</filter-name>
        <filter-class>br.com.stoom.web.CacheFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>gzipper</filter-name>
        <filter-class>br.com.stoom.web.GZIPFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>wsfilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>br.com.stoom.web.WebServiceFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>jsCssMinify</filter-name>
        <filter-class>br.com.stoom.web.JsCssMinifyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>blocker</filter-name>
        <filter-class>br.com.stoom.web.BlockFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>logger</filter-name>
        <filter-class>br.com.stoom.web.LogFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>blocker</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>logger</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>cacher</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>gzipper</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>gzipper</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>securityFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>messageFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>lazyLoadingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>lazyLoadingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xml</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>exportFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>lojaFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>wsfilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/wsIntegracao</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>logger</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/wsIntegracao</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>wsfilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/wsIntegracao/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>aberturaEmailFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/envio-email/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>threadFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.thread</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>jsCssMinify</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>jsCssMinify</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>XFireServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.codehaus.xfire.transport.http.XFireConfigurableServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>cssServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>br.com.stoom.web.CssServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cssServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/styles/loja/general.css</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>XFireServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet/XFireServlet/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>XFireServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/xservices/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>XFireServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/wsIntegracao</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>XFireServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/wsIntegracao/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>inc</extension>
        <mime-type>text/plain</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Connector</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.fredck.FCKeditor.connector.ConnectorServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>baseDir</param-name>
            <param-value>/UserFiles/</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SimpleUploader</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.fredck.FCKeditor.uploader.SimpleUploaderServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>baseDir</param-name>
            <param-value>/UserFiles/</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>enabled</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>AllowedExtensionsFile</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>DeniedExtensionsFile</param-name>
            <param-value>php|php3|php5|phtml|asp|aspx|ascx|jsp|cfm|cfc|pl|bat|exe|dll|reg|cgi</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>AllowedExtensionsImage</param-name>
            <param-value>jpg|gif|jpeg|png|bmp</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>DeniedExtensionsImage</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>AllowedExtensionsFlash</param-name>
            <param-value>swf|fla</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>DeniedExtensionsFlash</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Connector</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/tinyfck/filemanager/connectors/jsp/connector</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SimpleUploader</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/tinyfck/filemanager/upload/simpleuploader</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>503</error-code>
        <location>/503.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

Here is the **complete lists of jars** included in the application. It's a pretty big application. Maybe not all of them are needed (we lost track at this point), but most of them are. In the end are the jars related to spring and struts

```
>  oauth-20100527.jar google-collections-1.0-rc2.jar HikariCP-2.3.8.jar 

> javassist-3.18.2-GA.jar lucene-core-3.3.0.jar

> google-shopping-1.4.1.jar gdata-analytics-2.1.jar gdata-core-1.0.jar

> janalytics-1.0.jar jcommon-1.0.16.jar urlrewrite-2.5.2.jar

> dsn-1.4.5.jar javax.mail-1.4.5.jar activation-1.1.jar

> jasperreports-1.2.1.jar commons-digester-2.1.jar

> commons-logging-1.2.jar jfreechart-1.0.1.jar xml-apis-1.3.02.jar

> jdtcore-3.2.0.v_658.jar ajaxtags-1.1.5.jar jericho-html-1.5-dev1.jar

> spectjweaver-1.5.2a.jar commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar commons-pool-1.3.jar

> commons-collections-3.2.jar

> 

> commons-fileupload-1.3.2.jar commons-io-2.2.jar

> commons-httpclient-3.0.jar commons-codec-1.2.jar displaytag-1.1.1.jar

> itext-1.3.jar jcl104-over-slf4j-1.4.2.jar lf4j-log4j12-1.4.2.jar

> 2.0.1\dwr-2.0.1.jar jmock-1.1.0.jar junit-4.4.jar jwebunit-1.2.jar nekohtml-
0.8.1.jar httpunit-1.6.jar xmlParserAPIs-2.2.1.jar

> jtidy-4aug2000r7-dev.jar hibernate-3.2.5.ga.jar ehcache-1.2.3.jar

> jta-1.0.1B.jar asm-attrs-1.5.3.jar antlr-2.7.6.jar cglib-2.1_3.jar

> asm-1.5.3.jar hibernate-annotations-3.3.0.ga.jar

> persistence-api-1.0.jar hibernate-commons-annotations-3.3.0.ga.jar

> log4j-1.2.13.jar mysql-connector-java-5.0.5.jar

> postgresql-9.3-1103-jdbc41.jar jstl-1.1.2.jar log4j-api-2.5.jar

> commons-lang3-3.4.jar asm-commons-3.3.jar asm-tree-3.3.jar

> aopalliance-1.0.jar xfire-all-1.2.6.jar xfire-aegis-1.2.6.jar

> stax-utils-20040917.jar xfire-ws-security-1.2.6.jar opensaml-1.0.1.jar

> bcprov-jdk15-133.jar xercesImpl-2.7.1.jar xmlsec-1.3.0.jar

> wss4j-1.5.1.jar commons-discovery-0.2.jar xfire-core-1.2.6.jar

> wsdl4j-1.6.1.jar jaxen-1.1-beta-9.jar XmlSchema-1.1.jar

> wstx-asl-3.2.0.jar jdom-1.0.jar xfire-java5-1.2.6.jar

> xfire-jsr181-api-1.0-M1.jar xfire-generator-1.2.6.jar

> xfire-jaxb2-1.2.6.jar jaxb-xjc-2.0.1.jar jaxb-impl-2.0.1.jar

> xfire-xmlbeans-1.2.6.jar xbean-2.2.0.jar xfire-annotations-1.2.6.jar

> commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar commons-attributes-api-2.1.jar ant-1.5.jar

> qdox-1.5.jar xfire-jaxws-1.2.6.jar jaxws-api-2.0.jar jaxb-api-2.0.jar

> jsr173_api-1.0.jar saaj-impl-1.3.jar saaj-api-1.3.jar

> xfire-spring-1.2.6.jar xbean-spring-2.8.jar commons-email-1.1.jar

> cachefilter-1.0.1.jar slf4j-api-1.4.3.jar quartz-1.8.3.jar poi-3.9.jar

> poi-ooxml-3.9.jar poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar

> stax-api-1.0.1.jar dom4j-1.6.1.jar httpclient-4.2.1.jar

> httpcore-4.2.1.jar java-image-scaling-0.8.5.jar filters-2.0.235-1.jar

> jackson-core-2.3.0.jar jackson-databind-2.3.0.jar

> jackson-annotations-2.3.0.jar

> google-api-services-coordinate-v1-rev37-1.17.0-rc.jar

> google-api-client-1.17.0-rc.jar google-oauth-client-1.17.0-rc.jar

> google-http-client-jackson2-1.17.0-rc.jar

> google-http-client-1.17.0-rc.jar jsr305-1.3.9.jar

> google-http-client-appengine-1.17.0-rc.jar gson-2.2.4.jar

> aws-java-sdk-1.9.0.jar aws-java-sdk-directconnect-1.9.0.jar

> aws-java-sdk-core-1.9.0.jar joda-time-2.9.4.jar

> aws-java-sdk-logs-1.9.0.jar aws-java-sdk-elasticbeanstalk-1.9.0.jar

> aws-java-sdk-iam-1.9.0.jar aws-java-sdk-autoscaling-1.9.0.jar

> aws-java-sdk-emr-1.9.0.jar aws-java-sdk-cognitoidentity-1.9.0.jar

> aws-java-sdk-cloudwatchmetrics-1.9.0.jar

> aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch-1.9.0.jar aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.9.0.jar

> aws-java-sdk-ses-1.9.0.jar aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries-1.9.0.jar

> aws-java-sdk-simpleworkflow-1.9.0.jar

> aws-java-sdk-importexport-1.9.0.jar aws-java-sdk-support-1.9.0.jar

> aws-java-sdk-elasticache-1.9.0.jar aws-java-sdk-cloudfront-1.9.0.jar

> aws-java-sdk-opsworks-1.9.0.jar aws-java-sdk-storagegateway-1.9.0.jar

> aws-java-sdk-kinesis-1.9.0.jar aws-java-sdk-redshift-1.9.0.jar

> aws-java-sdk-cloudsearch-1.9.0.jar

> aws-java-sdk-cloudformation-1.9.0.jar aws-java-sdk-rds-1.9.0.jar

> aws-java-sdk-sts-1.9.0.jar aws-java-sdk-route53-1.9.0.jar

> aws-java-sdk-glacier-1.9.0.jar aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.9.0.jar

> aws-java-sdk-sns-1.9.0.jar aws-java-sdk-s3-1.9.0.jar

> aws-java-sdk-cloudtrail-1.9.0.jar aws-java-sdk-ec2-1.9.0.jar

> aws-java-sdk-cognitosync-1.9.0.jar aws-java-sdk-simpledb-1.9.0.jar

> aws-java-sdk-datapipeline-1.9.0.jar

> aws-java-sdk-elasticloadbalancing-1.9.0.jar

> aws-java-sdk-elastictranscoder-1.9.0.jar jbcrypt-0.3m.jar axis-1.4.jar

> axis-jaxrpc-1.4.jar javax.mail-api-1.5.4.jar maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar

> ant-1.8.0.jar ant-launcher-1.8.0.jar classworlds-1.1-alpha-2.jar

> plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-9-stable-1.jar

> plexus-utils-1.5.15.jar plexus-interpolation-1.11.jar

> maven-artifact-2.2.1.jar maven-artifact-manager-2.2.1.jar

> maven-repository-metadata-2.2.1.jar backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar

> maven-model-2.2.1.jar maven-project-2.2.1.jar maven-profile-2.2.1.jar

> maven-plugin-registry-2.2.1.jar maven-error-diagnostics-2.2.1.jar

> maven-settings-2.2.1.jar wagon-file-1.0-beta-6.jar

> wagon-http-lightweight-1.0-beta-6.jar wagon-http-shared-1.0-beta-6.jar

> wagon-provider-api-1.0-beta-6.jar guava-r09.jar xpp3-1.1.6.jar

> akarta-regexp-1.4.jar struts2-json-plugin-2.5.1.jar

> chaordic-api-1.0.0.jar

> chaordic-api-with-dependencies-1.0.0-dependencies.jar

> fckeditor-2.3.jar yuicompressor-2.3.6.jar mundipagg-1.0.jar

> sinetfactory-1.0.jar

> google-api-services-analytics-v3-rev116-1.20.0.jar

> (twelvemonkeys)imageio-jpeg-3.1.1.jar

> (twelvemonkeys)imageio-core-3.1.1.jar

> (twelvemonkeys)imageio-metadata-3.1.1.jar

> (twelvemonkeys)common-lang-3.1.1.jar

> (twelvemonkeys)common-io-3.1.1.jar

> (twelvemonkeys)common-image-3.1.1.jar (twelvemonkeys)servlet-3.1.1.jar

> ckeditor.filebrowser-3.5.2.0.jar rest-api-sdk-1.2.9.jar

> thumbnailator-0.4.8.jar

> ognl-3.1.8.jar 

> commons-lang-2.6.jar 

> servlet-api-2.4.jar

> (taglibs)standard-1.1.2.jar 

> sitemesh-2.4.1.jar 

> struts2-core-2.5.1.jar

> freemarker-2.3.23.jar 

> struts2-jasperreports-plugin-2.5.1.jar

> struts2-spring-plugin-2.5.1.jar 

> spring-core-3.2.14.RELEASE.jar

> spring-context-support-3.2.14.RELEASE.jar

> spring-beans-3.2.14.RELEASE.jar spring-context-3.2.14.RELEASE.jar

> spring-aop-3.2.14.RELEASE.jar spring-webmvc-3.2.14.RELEASE.jar

> spring-expression-3.2.14.RELEASE.jar spring-web-3.2.14.RELEASE.jar

> spring-orm-3.2.14.RELEASE.jar spring-jdbc-3.2.14.RELEASE.jar

> spring-tx-3.2.14.RELEASE.jar
```

Comment: Post the complete list of your jars with versions AND the complete web.xml. There's nothing wrong in the JSP you've posted

Comment: Are you using some custom theme? Can you post the FreeMarker stacktrace also.

Comment: Remove hidden field and you are fine.

Comment: Thanks for the replies!! I edited the question to include web.xml and the jars. I'm searching for that freemarker exception now to add it.

Regarding to the hidden field, when I remove it, It triggers the same error. In fact, changing all that code to a simple "<s:form> </s:form>" Will trigger the same error.

Comment: SiteMesh. See documentation for the S2 sitemesh plugin - https://struts.apache.org/docs/sitemesh-plugin.html.

Comment: Indeed there were differences between my web.xml filters organization and the one explicited in sitemesh plugin documentation

I changed my web.xml to reflect what says in the documentation: Declare struts-prepare, sitemesh and then struts-execute (in that order). I also added freemarker and struts listener (as it says in the documentation)


But none of that changed the error message

Comment: `action` attribute must point to an action not url, this is wrong `action="./filtro_BuscaAdm.html"`

Comment: I am having similar issue and posted my query in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52184043/struts2-surl-in-html-script-tag-not-working. Were you able to find a solution? This is a real pain.

Comment: It was mainly two things:  imcompatible jars in my application and broken tags in the jsp. I had to go through all the changelogs and find out wich tags were discontinued in the struts version I was installing. Also updated every f*** jar